# Oracle tablespaces for a 500gb DB

Tags: oracle

I have a database in SQL Server that I plan to migrate to Oracle but I want to know how the Tablespace configuration should be, I have investigated but I still have some doubts about how to implement it, my database in SQL Server has 3 filegroups pointing to disks different, it is 500gb, how would you recommend that I create the tablespace in Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tablespace implementation will depend somewhat on your data and your physical storage devices. While not strictly necessary (especially with Oracle 19c) a lot of people separate data and indexes into separate tablespaces, and sometimes LOBs too. If you're working with local disk drives on a physical server, then you probably want to separate the index tablespace and the data tablespace onto different disks or LVM volumes. If you are using Oracle ASM for storage, then physical separation is handled automatically. The number of files will be up to you, with max file size being OS-dependent. For many operating systems 32GB is the max file size for an individual data file, but you can add many files to each tablespace.